# Drop all files in Gridfs with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I would like to drop all the files in GridFS but I didn't manage to do it :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


#add the file to GridFS, per the pymongo documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gridfs.html
db_file = MongoClient('192.168.0.16', 27017).db_file
fs = gridfs.GridFS( db_file )

db_file.drop_collection('files')
db_file.drop_collection('chunks')
db_file.drop_collection('test')
out = fs.get(ObjectId('57683734f525bc3d7420c262'))
print(out)
fp = open("test.mp3", 'wb')
fp.write(out.read())
fp.close()
```

At the end of the code i still have a file created and i can still play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> my_collection = db['collection_name']
>   my_collection.drop()

or drop database :

> client = MongoClient('192.168.0.16', 27017)
>       client.drop_database("database_name")